# Why people often adopt repeated adjective structure on their sentence?

Tags: sentence, writing-style, syntactic-analysis

Why people often adopt repeated adjective structure on their sentence?

For example: Great courtiers are gracious and polite; their aggression is veiled and indirect.

I have seen many fluent English speaker adopted this style. Does this style have a name? Do other sentence style exist?

Comment: How is this "repeated adjective"? It should be called something like conjoined adjectives.

Comment: Why d'you think that's in any way remarkable, please? Is it that in other languages, adjectives should only be used singly? Because there's no such rule in English, your Question is meaningful only in grammar…

Answer (score -2):

Using synonymous adjectives is poor style, often adopted by writers or speakers who are tying to appear intelligent by using a lot of words. Adept English speakers and writers avoid redundancy.  After all, brevity is the soul of wit!

Comment: I think you'll find that's not true but since you posted it as an Answer, could you justify it with three or four examples, please?